# How to assign a value to an object property using variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I'm working on Reacr app. I have an object like this:

```
state = {
    property1: 'value',
    property2: 'value',
    property3: 'value',
    property4: 'value',
}
```

I want to assign a value to this object property through a function:

```
myFunc = (i) => {
     this.setState({
          this.state[i] = 'newValue'
     })  
}
```

But it can't be done because in this way I will directly mutate the state object. So I have a question how to get object property name and then assign a value to it? It would be nice if it can be possible in JavaScript to:

```
this.state[i] : 'ft-post ft-post-show'
```

Thank you for any ideas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set the value using an object assignment with with dynamic key syntax like

```
myFunc = (i) => {
     this.setState({
          [i]:  'ft-post ft-post-show'
     })  
}
```

Comment: Yes, so simple )) Thank you